# Reasoning about threads and time outs: Could providing a timeout improve performance for a multithreaded application?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

I have an java application that uses 60 threads in a thread pool where each thread makes an SOAP request to export data to a server.  Our goal is to export as much data as possible as quickly possible.

We've recently noticed that the promised time out on the server-side is not happening.  We were told that there was a 90 second time out which we were asked to tolerate.

Instead, we are seeing that sometimes, an error response doesn't come back for over 200 seconds.  This is a latent issue that has been happening all along.

I am wondering if this is an opportunity to improve our export rate or if changing the time out rate, on our side, to 90 seconds will not change a thing.

We have found that roughly 60 threads provides the optimal output.  If we increase it to 70 threads or 120 threads for example, we see no increase in export rate.

If we reduce thread count below 60 threads, we see a decrease in our export rate.

Assuming that the average response time for an error is 120 seconds (which always indicates an error) and a non-error is less than 30 seconds, would we necessarily gain any performance benefit by setting the time out to 90 seconds?  Or would the fact that increasing threads didn't help indicate that we are already at the maximum export rate?

Comment: You will want to study [Queueing Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queueing_theory), and by constructing a model of your system using Markov chains calculate the throughput using that.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I'll read up on queueing theory and Markov chains.